# kivy: installed as module, DLL load failed but works with kivy.bat

Tags: python, kivy

I used kivy by  running applications with the kivy.bat script packaged with the standalone version. To have better support when using pycharm (autocomplete) I  installed kivy using `pip`. The problem is that when I run my application it gives the error below. Running it with the standalone kivy.bat script it runs fine.

```
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\lucas\.kivy\logs\kivy_14-07-07_0.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/lucas/PycharmProjects/code_reviewer/gui/interface.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\tools\lib\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 329, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\tools\lib\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 88, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import Canvas
   File "C:\tools\lib\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix the `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` error?

Comment: Did the pip install actually work? I don't think the compiled components are present. Not sure how to fix this on windows though (dependencies etc).

Answer (score 2):

I have reinstalled the Python, I have uninstalled a few GTK+ versions and I have removed glew DLL from the system 32 folder to supress this error. As I think, the glew DLL was the reason of the error.

Comment: Removing `glow.dll` from `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` seemed to solve the issue for me. (I placed it there by mistake and forgot to remove it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install some of the dependency packages, specifically kivy.deps.glew and kivy.deps.sdl2 solved the "DLL load failed" problem for me.